# I want to understand the inner working of a Collections.List<T>

Tags: c#

I've created my own list with a static int as length. How are these things done when you don't know the size of a collection and you want to construct it. I know there is a build in list but I want to build my own to understand the inner working of it. I defined it as size = int 5 in the constructor so it will output now 1 2 3 0 0 and I want to know how to resize it and using a constructor with undefined length. I can't figure it out myself some help is appreciated.

I fixed it. Thanks for the answers guys really fast and easy to understand I never heard from the .net reference so thanks for the site.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List l = new List();
        l.Add(1);
        l.Add(2);
        l.Add(3);
        l.Add(4);

        foreach (int n in l)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}

class List
{
    private int _lLength;
    private int[] _lArray;
    private int _lPos;

    public List()
    {
        /*
         * Create an array with a default size
         * If it doesn't fit anymore create a new one and copy it
         * to a new array and double the size
         */
        this._lArray = new int[2];
    }

    public List(int c)
    {
        this._lLength = c;
        this._lArray = new int[this._lLength];
        this._lPos = 0;
    }

    public void Add(int n)
    {
        if (this._lArray.Length <= this._lPos)
        {
            // So now is the array < then the array we want to return
            int[] tmp = this._lArray;
            this._lArray = new int[tmp.Length * 2];
            Array.Copy(tmp, this._lArray, tmp.Length);
        }

        this._lArray[this._lPos++] = n;
    }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (int n in this._lArray)
            yield return n;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The generic `List<T>` supplied with the framework defaults to a capacity of 4 and simply doubles in size when a resize is required. It maintains an internal array and copies to a new array on a resize.

Comment: If you want to understand the inner workings, look at the source: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs#cf7f4095e4de7646

Comment: You may want to re-implement InsertRange, though. It can be mega-slow :)

Answer (score 1):

Internally, the `List<T>` object keeps an array with a default size (0, according to the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs#cf7f4095e4de7646)). When the array is full, a new array is created, double size of the previous one, and all items from the first array are moved to the new array.

So adding an item to this list (array size = 2):

- item 1
- item 2

Causes the array behind the list to become (array size = 4):

- item 1
- item 2
- item 3
- null

If you know the probable size of the list on beforehand, you could opt to pass the expected number to the constructor of `List<T>`. The array size will be set to that length, which may give you better performance overall, since it doesn't have to recreate arrays.